# PHP: How to write code to play video files (not flash) but completely turn off the video download

Tags: php, video

PHP: How to write code in PHP to play video files (not flash) but completely turn off the video download

Yahoo sites do it so far I saw

Comment: Any chance you can provide URL(s) of pages which have the behaviours you are wanting?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via PHP AFAIK. You have to use JavaScript or HTML5  tag. The problem with HTML5 is, that not every browser supports it yet.